# Web API calls Authentication in WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have tried searching for samples in implementing authentication  using WSO2 Identity Server for web API calls residing in other servers but cant seem to find one. I can only find authentications on WSO2 IS API calls. Can you refer some links for examples or tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the admin APIs using following way.

1. Start the server using -DosgiConsole flag, i.e. `./wso2server.sh -DosgiConsole` or `./wso2server.bat -DosgiConosle`
2. Then after the server start you will get the osgi console. Enter listAdminServices and you will get the list. ex:

> ```
> osgi> listAdminServices
> Admin services deployed on this server:
>
> 1. ProvisioningAdminService, ProvisioningAdminService, https://10.150.3.140:9443/services/ProvisioningAdminService/
> ```

All the commands such as `listAdminServices` are listed by typing `help` from the osgi console.

By default, these admin APIs are hides, you have to enable them. To do that, change `<ESB_HOME>/repository/conf/carbon.xml` file.

```
<!-- If this parameter is set, the ?wsdl on an admin service will not give the admin service wsdl. -->
<HideAdminServiceWSDLs>false</HideAdminServiceWSDLs>
```

Note: All servers expose Web Service APIs which can be used for to gain access to back end functionality.